# How to ignore blanks in dynamic ranges when using Excel name manager

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I am trying to use data validation drop down lists to identify a particular employee and then once that is updated, I have VBA update other data.

Sample Data:

```
**Red** **Green** **Blue**

Jim     Sue       Nancy

Andrea  Laura     Katie

Greg    Brian
        
Tim
```

Then I have two data validation cells:

```
Team: [Data validation list for =$A$1:$C$1]

Name: [Data validation list for =INDIRECT(H1))
```

I would like to have it so I can add/remove names from the sample data but the name cell will only ever show what values are within that column.

I have tried multiple iterations of OFFSET that I found in other threads but still no luck (just returns a {...} value).

Examples:

=OFFSET(Sheet1!$C$1,1,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$C:$C)-1,10)
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$C$2,0,0,COUNTIF(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$7,"?*")-1)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So your named range "Red" is Jim etc and you want to be able to delete Andrea and the list shows Jim, Greg and Tim?

Comment: https://www.teachexcel.com/excel-tutorial/ignore-blanks-in-a-data-validation-list-in-excel_1302.html

Comment: Yes, or conversely, I want to add another name and that name is captured as well. So effectively, if "Red" is selected in H1, H2 would show values in cells A2:A100 but only return the cells that have a value.